# Process the command without launching MainActivity, in Android

Tags: java, android, android-activity, screen

I am new to android and stuck at one point with my new screen off test application. I am trying to develop an Android application to turn off or lock the screen directly by clicking the app launcher icon of the application.

I am able to lock the screen with the functionality I want but with one problem. While i click on the screen lock icon in the launcher **it takes around a second and then locks the screen** (Time is taken by to MainActivity to launch).

I want that time delay to be removed and just wanted to process the command to lock phone when user tap on the app icon in the launcher. But am not able to figure it out.

Here is **AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<application
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoDisplay"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:allowBackup="true">

    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:excludeFromRecents="true"
        android:launchMode="singleTask">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <receiver android:name="ScreenOffAdminReceiver"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_DEVICE_ADMIN">
        <meta-data android:name="android.app.device_admin"
            android:resource="@xml/permissions" />
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.app.action.DEVICE_ADMIN_ENABLED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

</application>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    protected void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
        super.onCreate(bundle);
        DevicePolicyManager deviceManger = (DevicePolicyManager) getSystemService(Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE);
        ComponentName compName = new ComponentName(this, ScreenOffAdminReceiver.class);
        if (deviceManger.isAdminActive(compName)) {
            deviceManger.lockNow();
            finish();
        } else {
            Intent intent = new Intent("android.app.action.ADD_DEVICE_ADMIN");
            intent.putExtra("android.app.extra.DEVICE_ADMIN", compName);
            intent.putExtra("android.app.extra.ADD_EXPLANATION", getString(R.string.devicePolicyManagerMsg));
            startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
        }
        Process.killProcess(Process.myPid());
    }
}
```

**ScreenOffAdminReceiver.java**

```
public class ScreenOffAdminReceiver extends DeviceAdminReceiver {
    public void onDisabled(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Toast.makeText(context, R.string.deviceAdminDisabled, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    public void onEnabled(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Toast.makeText(context, R.string.deviceAdminEnabled, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

**permissions.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<device-admin xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <uses-policies>
        <force-lock />
    </uses-policies>
</device-admin>
```

I just want to remove the DELAY while locking the screen. Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Can you share `permissions.xml`?

Comment: Have you tried without performing `Process.killProcess(Process.myPid())`? I feel like it may make some issues.

Comment: Yes i tried without it also but when some new application opens up then the process get automatically killed and again the same problem comes

Comment: Do you experience that particularly on one/specific devices?

Comment: No i tested it on three different device

Comment: I studied a source code of one of the screen lock application by de-compiling it via JADX. It is functioning properly with the exact similar code.

Comment: @kanudo The correct way to do it, throw simple `Widget` That is how other applications work. You create widget, as icon, and when you interaction with them throw simple CLICK, you sending `PendingIntent` to another your `BroadcastReceiver` with some action. And this all executes as fast, as it possible.

Comment: @GensaGames I do not want this as an widget, cause widgets can only be placed on home screens and not in the dock. I have some other usages that need the icon also to appear in the dock. Is there any way that i can make this application running in background starting at boot and whenever the application icon is clicked the command gets processed.

Comment: @kanudo Have tried using a floating button along with a service like Facebook chat head?

Comment: @TdSoft right now i want it to work like an application hence haven't tried that.

Answer (score 4):

I think you should use Application Class

```
public class MainApplication  extends Application {
 @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
/*
        you should code here */
}

}
```

Comment: I tried it out, it just reduces the time taken to half. Is there any way that i can keep this process continuous. Because that is the way that the application will not have to be loaded every time and hence the time to launch the application gets removed.

Answer (score 2):

You can try decrease time of app launch (create activity) with change theme settings:

Try use in your app style:

```
<item name="android:windowDisablePreview">true</item>
<item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help you out.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    DevicePolicyManager deviceManger;
    ComponentName compName;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        deviceManger = (DevicePolicyManager) getSystemService(DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE);
        compName = new ComponentName(this, ScreenOffAdminReceiver.class);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        if (deviceManger.isAdminActive(compName)) {
            deviceManger.lockNow();
            finish();
        } else {
            Intent intent = new Intent("android.app.action.ADD_DEVICE_ADMIN");
            intent.putExtra("android.app.extra.DEVICE_ADMIN", compName);
            intent.putExtra("android.app.extra.ADD_EXPLANATION", "Device Policies");
            startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you could achieve near zero response time as long as your "trigger" is clicking on the app launcher icon for two reasons:

1. When you click on the app icon a request is sent to the "system" (if you want to read more about it - it's called the zygote process).
   The system then creates the process for your application to run and only then the app is launched.
   This is guaranteed to take some time.
2. The first code to be executed is your application `onCreate()` method BUT if your application is still kept in the background/phone memory this method won't be executed when clicking on the app launcher icon, so this solution is not really what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I think it'll be faster if instead of locking the screen from the app you can create a widget to do the same. It will be faster and more efficient.
[This might help you](http://www.androidauthority.com/create-simple-android-widget-608975/)

Comment: Yes you are right, but I like to have the icon in the Dock and want an app feel instead of a widget feel.